# SQL Server 2008 + C# + Inno Installer

Tags: c#, sql-server, sql-server-2008, inno-setup

First off I´m new here, so, I'd say HELLO EVERYONE and thanks for years of helping.

I have the following problem:

I need create a installation of a C# app that uses SQL Server 2008. I am using InnoSetup Installer because I thought it could be the best choice, but I have no clue how to install SQL Server 2008, and several databases (.mdf, .ldf or .bak) which should be installed on the local machine.

So my task is, having the C# app and the SQL Server 2008 engine + tools in my computer, to distribute it to my clients in a unattended manner (because the fact that they're using a database should be transparent to the end user).

I´m sure it is possible, actually I install the C# app, and the SQL Server engine (downloaded `SQLEXP32_x86_ENY.exe`), but what about the databases? That is my problem, as well as a correct configuration of SQL SERVER: because as you probably know, it is not so trivial make it work properly (Access control problems, Administrator Rights, and so on).

For example in order to install SQL Server I do it in console mode, as Microsoft blesses, doing:

```
SQLEXP32_x86_ENY.exe /ACTION=install /FEATURES=SQL,Tools
/INSTANCENAME=SQLExpress
/SECURITYMODE=SQL /SAPWD=****
/SQLSYSADMINACCOUNTS="Builtin\Administrators"
\ENABLERANU /SQLSVCACCOUNT=""
/SQLSVCPASSWORD=""
```

What should I write in /SQLSVCACCOUNT /SQLSVCPASSWORD,  for example?

What should I do to import my existing databases I provide? Until lately people used to use SQLDMO CMO object, but I read that that is not longer supported.

How do you do that? That's the question, at least dome tips could be useful.

My client needs a database locally, but at the beginning they need to have created some databases as well as some initial data in.

Thanks in advance!!!

Answer (score 1):

First off, you are aware that the file `SQLEXP32_x86_ENY.exe` you downloaded is the SQL Server **Express** edition - right? It's free, even for commercial purposes, but it does have a few limitations (only uses 1 CPU, max. DB size limited to 4 GB and a few more).

Second, for your `SQLSVCACCOUNT` - best practice for a production environment is to have a special system account for running SQL Server under - something like a "artificial" user called `SQLServerUser` or whatever you want to call it. This account has a password, and those are the two things you would have supply for `SQLSVCACCOUNT` and `SQLSVCPASSWORD`.

For a development environment, those settings are typically set to something like `SYSTEM\NETWORK SERVICE` or `NT AUTHORITY\LOCAL SYSTEM` something similar (for the account).

As for attaching existing databases to the new SQL Server instance - you have several options:

- if you can do it interactively, download and install the SQL Server Management Studio Express edition and attach your databases in that tool
- if you need to do it during install, you can e.g. use `sqlcmd` - the command line SQL tool - to execute a SQL statement like `ATTACH DATABASE ......` directly from the command line. `sqlcmd` is installed with SQL Server (including Express editions)
- if you need to have full control, you could use the SMO - SQL Server Management Objects - that get installed with SQL Server 2008 to automate your task (instead of the legacy SQL-DMO which is no longer supported)

Comment: Should/Can the artificial SQLServerUser user and associated password be created automatically and transparently by the InnoSetup installation program?

Comment: Yes, it definitely could - there's plenty of API's to create a new user in Windows and setting properties for it

Answer (score 0):

Finally I will work with SQL SERVER COMPACT 3.5 ... It gieves me enough resources for my proposes, and is kinda easier to deploy. 
As well, I will be sure my users don´t user the database in bad manner...
thanks!!!!! 
Anyway, I will continous trying to deploy correctly an SQL SERVER 2008, but Vista is a pain in  the arse!hahaah

Thanks marc_s!!!!!!!!!!